# Export SVG as Image with custom Icon Font

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, fonts, export

I hope someone can help me with this problem:

The goal is to save an inline SVG as an PNG image.

The problem is that said SVG has `foreignObject` elements containing webfont icons (from Fontawesome as well as custom ones created with [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)).

To export the SVG as PNG I used the approach described in [Save inline SVG as JPEG/PNG/SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226677/save-inline-svg-as-jpeg-png-svg).
To get the right view of the SVG I copied all computed styles to a copy of the svg Element as inline styles (copy to not pollute the original one). But since font icons are only embedded in HTML as `::before` elements and those do not work as inline styles they were left out when exporting the SVG.
My workaround was putting the unicode of the icon glyph as `innerHTML` of the `i` tag and let SVG handle it like normal text.

The problem here was that the exported image did not have access to the fonts containing the icons. So I tried using the workaround discribed in [Including fonts when converting SVG to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105468/including-fonts-when-converting-svg-to-png) and embed the base64 encoded version of the icon font inside the svgs `defs --> style` tags. First problem with this approach was that I couldn't use `btoa()` directly because I added the icons unicode characters but for this is used the first solution described in [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#solution_1_%E2%80%93_escaping_the_string_before_encoding_it).

But after all this I still can't get the icons to show up on the exported image and I'm out of ideas...

Here is how the web version of the SVG looks like:
[image: Inline SVG as seen inside the web app]

Here is how the exported version looks like:
[image: Exported picture of SVG]

Here is the code for exporting:

```
download(selector: string, name: string): void {
    const svg = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(selector + ' svg')
    const svgCopy = svg.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement

    this.computedToInline(svg, svgCopy)

    const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.querySelector('canvas')

    canvas.width = svg.getBoundingClientRect().width
    canvas.height = svg.getBoundingClientRect().height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    if (!ctx) return

    const data = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgCopy)

    const image = new Image()
    const encodedData = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)))
    const url = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + encodedData

    image.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)

        const imageURI = canvas
            .toDataURL('image/png')
            .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream')

        this.triggerDownload(imageURI, name)
    }

    image.src = url
}

computedToInline(element: HTMLElement, elementCopy: HTMLElement): void {
    if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (let i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
            this.computedToInline(
                element.children[i] as HTMLElement,
                elementCopy.children[i] as HTMLElement
            )
        }
    }

    const computedStyles = getComputedStyle(element)
    for (let i = 0; i < computedStyles.length; i++) {
        const style = computedStyles[i]
        elementCopy.style.setProperty(style, computedStyles.getPropertyValue(style))
    }

    if (element.classList.contains('icon')) {
        elementCopy.style.font = '900 14px "Custom Icon Font"'
        // the text ICON is just added for visualisation purpose
        elementCopy.innerHTML = 'ICON\ue900'
    }
}
```

The font in the SVG is embedded like so:
Base64 encoded font embedded in SVG
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the approach you are following from another answer.
I earlier used saveSvgAsPng npm package, it works like charm.

1. Install package

```js
    npm install save-svg-as-png
```

2. Use it by hmtl id of element you want to export as image like :

```js
    saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("IdOfHTMLDiv"), "ImageName.png");
```

You can also export as `svgAsDataUri` or `svgAsPngUri`

For adding fonts, you can use options like

```
const imageOptions = {
      fonts: [
        {
          url: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2',
          format: 'application/font-woff2',
          text: "@font-face {font-family: 'Roboto';  font-style: normal;  font-weight: 400; src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}",
        },
        {
          url: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sharetechmono/v9/J7aHnp1uDWRBEqV98dVQztYldFcLowEFA87Heg.woff2',
          format: 'application/font-woff2',
          text: "@font-face {font-family: 'Share Tech Mono'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('Share Tech Mono'), local('ShareTechMono-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sharetechmono/v9/J7aHnp1uDWRBEqV98dVQztYldFcLowEFA87Heg.woff2) format('woff2'); unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD; }",
        }
      ],
    };

svgAsPngUri(document.getElementById("diagram"), imageOptions).then(uri => ...)
```

Refer [Github Page](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng) for more details